# Books on Catastrophe Theory

Tags: reference-request, dynamical-systems, book-recommendation, catastrophe-theory

I'm looking for a technical introduction to catastrophe theory, preferably something short.

I have a good background so graduate level texts are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Dover is usually short, sweet, and cheap: "Catastrophe Theory and Its Applications" - Tim Poston & Ian Stewart (http://www.amazon.com/dp/048669271X/ )